# Restore button not changing to maximize button in my WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application where my form dervies from `Form`.

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            //I do something here
        //*what I have tried*
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        //end of *what I have tried*
        base.OnResize(e);
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            //I do a few things here
        }
        else if (bMinimized)
            //I do a few things here
    }
```

After I maximize the form, I can resize/restore the form by double clicking the title bar and the maximize button appears in place of the restore button. But instead of double clicking the title bar, if I drag the form by clicking and holding the title bar, the form is restored and, the OnResize event fires but the maximize button does not appear. I have to click on the restore button once again to make the maximize button appear. Why is this happening? Am I not handling any event that signals that the resizing has completed when clicking and dragging is performed.

Comment: I set the Window state to normal in the hope that it would lead to the maximize button being shown instead of the restore button. But it did not help in any way.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: *if I drag the form by clicking and holding the title bar, the form is restored*. The form is in a normal state (not maximized nor minimized), then you click the title bar and hold, and the form restores just by dragging? Or do you meant when you drag to the top of the screen, where windows 7+ restores it automatically? Anyway, just a shot, try calling `base.OnResize(e);` before everything in your `OnResize`.

Comment: @Alisson The form is maximized and I click and drag the form it gets restored as soon as I start dragging. But the restored form should have the maximize button, instead it continues to display the restore button

Comment: I wrote a simple program with two buttons, "Maximize" and "Restore". Visibility of each is set in `OnResize()` overload according to the current window state; if maximized, "Restore" button is shown, otherwise "Maximize" button is shown. The buttons correctly track the state of the window, regardless of how it's changed, including dragging a maximized form by the title bar to restore it. Your question fails the crucial requirement of providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. You'll need to fix it if you want a good, useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I think if you create a bool variable called "isMaximzed". Then whenever the form is maximized, our variable is set to true. and the maximize button goes away.

using if statements with one if and else statement so it looks like so.  This way there can only be one state....the form is either maximized or it isn't.

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
    {
        isMaximized = false;

    } else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        isMaximized  = true;
    }

   if (isMaximized == true) {

       // don't show maximize button
     } else 
     {
         // show maximized button
     }
```

I hope you get the point

Comment: @Jamisco The problem is not showing/hiding maximize button. The default behaviour of WinForms, where restore button becomes maximize button when the form is restored by dragging it(when it is in maximized state) is not happening. To make it more clear try the following. On the current browser window(not tab, but the whole browser window), maximize, then click on the title bar and drag it, you will notice that the restore button changes to maximize as soon as the window is dragged(and it get resized). This behaviour is not seen in my case.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, doesn't the Win forms already automatically hide/show the maximize buttons?.. Mine does... But I can suggest that you try making a new form then look at its default properties and change them in your main form respectively